# how to bulk remove documents in MongoDB after finding them in mongo console?

Tags: mongodb

I want to ease my life and not to write any code for find some documents inside a collection and then remove them and I want to do this by using mongo console :

```
$ db.collection.find({something here which has reutrn value }).find()
```

I want to do something similar to following :

```
$ db.collection.find({something here which has reutrn value }).find().remove()
```

and it is not possible , so what is the fastest way of get rid of some documents without coding? or without knowing document's ID?

Answer (score 6):

This is how you remove documents:

```
db.things.remove({your_query});
```

You could find them first with:

```
db.things.find({your_query}).pretty();
```

See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Removing